# Unable to add more than one applications together in cherryPy

Tags: python, typeerror, cherrypy

When I do this and try to access "/api" than cherryPy throws "TypeError: 'ApiStringGenerator' object is not callable" error

```
'''
Created on Jan 11, 2016

@author: ankurjat
'''
import cherrypy
import random
import string
import os

conf = {'/': {'tools.sessions.on': True,
              'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())},
        '/static': {'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                    'tools.staticdir.dir': './resources'},
        '/api': {'request.dispatch':  cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
                 'tools.sessions.on': True,
                 'tools.response_headers.on': True,
                 'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')]}
            }


class ApiStringGenerator(object):
    exposed = True

    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
    def GET(self, length=8):
        value = cherrypy.session['mystring']
        return value

    def POST(self, length=8):
        value = ''.join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, int(length)))
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = value
        return value

    def PUT(self, value):
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = value

    def DELETE(self):
        cherrypy.session.pop('mystring', None)


class StringGenerator(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return file('templates/index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.tree.mount(ApiStringGenerator(), '/api', conf)
    cherrypy.tree.mount(StringGenerator(), '/', conf)

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

But when I change below lines

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(ApiStringGenerator(), '/api', conf)
cherrypy.tree.mount(StringGenerator(), '/', conf)

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

By the code

```
webapp = StringGenerator()
webapp.api = ApiStringGenerator()
cherrypy.quickstart(webapp, '/', conf)
```

Then no error and everything works fine.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the configuration in cherrypy is relative to the mountpoint.

So when you are configuring the `MethodDispatcher` in `/api` inside the mount point `/api`. You are activating the `MethodDispatcher` inside `/api/api` and the dispatcher that's gets used in `/api` it's the default one, hence trying to call the object because the object has the `exposed` attribute but it's not callable. Which is the behavior of the default dispatcher.

If you want to do:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(ApiStringGenerator(), '/api', conf)
```

The configuration needs to be relative to the `/api`:

```
 {'/': {'request.dispatch':  cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.response_headers.on': True,
        'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type',  'text/plain')]}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cyraxjoe. It worked. Now I created two conf dictionary,

one for '/' and another for '/api' and in their conf dict I mounted them on '/' and it worked. :)